# Theory of computer science problems

Tags: python, computer-science, dfa, nfa

I am working on theory of computer science problems but cannot get these to work:

> a. Give an NFA recognizing the language (01 ∪ 001 ∪ 010)<sup>*</sup>
>
> b. Convert this NFA to an equivalent DFA. Give only the portion of the DFA that is reachable from the start state.
>
> [image: 1.49 Theory]

I am using the `automata.fa` package to encode the automata and have them tested. Here are examples:

```
# example DFA syntax
example_dfa = DFA(
    states={'q1', 'q2', 'q3', 'q4', 'q5'},
    input_symbols={'0', '1'},
    transitions={
        'q1': {'0': 'q1', '1': 'q2'},
        'q2': {'0': 'q1', '1': 'q3'},
        'q3': {'0': 'q2', '1': 'q4'},
        'q4': {'0': 'q3', '1': 'q5'},
        'q5': {'0': 'q4', '1': 'q5'}
    },
    initial_state='q3',
    final_states={'q3'}
)

# example NFA syntax
example_nfa = NFA(
    states={"q0", "q1", "q2"},
    input_symbols={"0", "1"},
    transitions={
        "q0": {"": {"q1", "q2"}},
        "q1": {"0": {"q1"}, "1": {"q2"}},
        "q2": {"0": {"q1"}, "1": {"q2"}},
    },
    initial_state="q0",
    final_states={"q1"},
)

# example regular expression syntax
example_regex = "(a*ba*(a|b)*)|()"
```

For the above question, I tried with the following diagram for the NFA:

```
from automata.fa.nfa import NFA

prob_1_17a = NFA(
    states={'q0', 'q1', 'q2', 'q3'},
    input_symbols={'0', '1'},
    transitions={
        'q0': {'0': {'q3'}, '1': {'q0'}},
        'q1': {'0': {'q1'}, '1': {'q0'}},
        'q2': {'0': {'q0'}, '1': {'q2'}},
        'q3': {'0': {'q1'}, '1': {'q2'}},
    },
    initial_state='q0',
    final_states={'q0'}
)
```

but the autograder gives the following output:

> Results:
>
> Running command:
>
> ```
> $ timeout 15 python3 unit_tests/unit_test_prob_1_17a.py
> ```
>
> UNEXPECTED RESULT ON THESE INPUTS:
>
> ```
> ['01', '00101', '01001', '01010', '010101', '00100101', '00101001', '00101010', '01000101', '01001001', ...]
> ```
>
> Test for: unit_test_prob_1_17a.py
>
> This test gave you 0 more points

How to design the correct NFA/DFA?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your attempt to an NFA can be visualised like this:

[image]

This is not correct. For instance, it allows input to start with a 1, which the language does not allow. The loop at q<sub>2</sub> would allow an input to have consecutive 1s, but that is never possible. The loop at q<sub>1</sub> would allow the input to have *any* sequence of 0s, but the language can never accept a string that has four or more consecutive 0s.

On the other hand your attempt does not accept the valid input "01", because the state will be at q<sub>2</sub> after such input, and that is not an accept state in your NFA.

### How to design the NFA

To design an NFA for the language (01 ∪ 001 ∪ 010)<sup>*</sup> we could take it step by step. First design a diagram for the language (01)<sup>*</sup>:

[image: nfa1]

q<sub>0</sub> is the start and accept state, and q<sub>4</sub> is the sink for invalid input. Then extend it to (01 ∪ 001)<sup>*</sup>:

[image: nfa2]

And then complete to (01 ∪ 001 ∪ 010)<sup>*</sup>:

[image]

### How to design the DFA from the NFA

To design a corresponding DFA, define a state for each possible set of states in the NFA. So for instance (<sub>1</sub>,<sub>2</sub>) is one such state, and (<sub>0</sub>,<sub>1</sub>,<sub>2</sub>) is another. There are many of such states, but only some are really reachable.

Using [powerset construction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Powerset_construction) we can identify which input prefixes lead to which states in the NFA, and we can assign to each unique state combination a distinct DFA state. As soon as we find a same combination of NFA states that we already encountered with another prefix, we don't need to lengthen that prefix more, and so we get this table of possibilities:

| prefix | NFA states | DFA state |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ε | <sub>0</sub> | <sub>0</sub> |
| 0 | <sub>1</sub>,<sub>2</sub> | <sub>12</sub> |
| 00 | <sub>1</sub> | <sub>1</sub> |
| 000 | <sub>4</sub> | <sub>4</sub> |
| 001 | <sub>0</sub> | <sub>0</sub> |
| 01 | <sub>0</sub>,<sub>3</sub> | <sub>03</sub> |
| 010 | <sub>0</sub>,<sub>1</sub>,<sub>2</sub> | <sub>012</sub> |
| 0100 | <sub>1</sub>,<sub>2</sub> | <sub>12</sub> |
| 0101 | <sub>0</sub>,<sub>3</sub> | <sub>03</sub> |
| 011 | <sub>4</sub> | <sub>4</sub> |
| 1 | <sub>4</sub> | <sub>4</sub> |

I chose names for the states of the DFA that reflect how they map to a set of states in the NFA. Each DFA state that corresponds to an NFA state combination that includes <sub>0</sub> is accepting.

This leads to the following DFA:

[image]

#### Python code

The above NFA and DFA can be represented as follows:

```py
nfa = NFA(
    states={'q0', 'q1', 'q2', 'q3', 'q4'},
    input_symbols={'0', '1'},
    transitions={
        'q0': {'0': {'q1','q2'}, '1': {'q4'}},
        'q1': {'0': {'q4'},      '1': {'q0'}},
        'q2': {'0': {'q1'},      '1': {'q3'}},
        'q3': {'0': {'q0'},      '1': {'q4'}},
        'q4': {'0': {'q4'},      '1': {'q4'}} # Sink
    },
    initial_state='q0',
    final_states={'q0'}
)

dfa = DFA(
    states={'q0', 'q1', 'q12', 'q03', 'q012', 'q4'},
    input_symbols={'0', '1'},
    transitions={
        'q0'  : {'0': 'q12',  '1': 'q4' },
        'q12' : {'0': 'q1',   '1': 'q03'},
        'q1'  : {'0': 'q4',   '1': 'q0' },
        'q03' : {'0': 'q012', '1': 'q4' },
        'q012': {'0': 'q12',  '1': 'q03'},
        'q4':   {'0': 'q4',   '1': 'q4' } # Sink
    },
    initial_state='q0',
    final_states={'q0', 'q03', 'q012'}
)
```